# How to create a new column ‘Request_Closing_Time’ as the time elapsed between request creation and request closing in python

Tags: python, pandas

The given columns are ‘Created Date’ and Closed Date’. Both columns were objects datatype but I managed to convert them both to datetime. I am not sure how to create a new column Request_closing_time. Please assist me in that regard

Comment: Please explain better what should be in the new column

Comment: The question is phrased as: Read or convert the columns ‘Created Date’ and Closed Date’ to datetime datatype and create a new column ‘Request_Closing_Time’ as the time elapsed between request creation and request closing. (Hint: Explore the package/module datetime).

Comment: I have already done the first parts in the dataframe. I just need to know whether if the new column("Requested_closing_time") will be the difference between closing data and created date or automatically the datetime module will create the elapsed time.